# Share Account Records

Tags: sharing

Here i have so many records are there at account level and also i have created so many users.

Now here i want to share one specific account's record to specific user means only this user can see that particular account's record not other user.

Can some one help me on this.Can some one guide me with steps so i can perform this task.

Thanks in advance for your support

Answer (score 1):

1. Make the OWD account sharing model as private
2. Make the user the owner of the account.

That is the simplistic answer.

The more complex issue is the decision of how you are going to handle security according to your business model. General rule is if even ONE user should not see a record, then the OWD for that object should be set to private. Access can then be granted in a variety of ways

This Security Workbook is a good place to start:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_security/workbook_security.pdf